# Django-Rest-Framework AttributeError object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I facing this bellow error after trying to input data via DRF

```
    File "G:\partshouse\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework_simplejwt\tokens.py", line 176, in for_user
    user_id = getattr(user, api_settings.USER_ID_FIELD)
AttributeError: 'TestBookingSerializer' object has no attribute 'id'
[17/Apr/2022 02:11:40] "POST /api/testbooking/ HTTP/1.1" 500 17894
```

**Serializer.py**

```
class TestBookingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = PendingBooking
    fields = ['booking_id', 'cus_name', 'cus_unique_id', 'created_by', 'date', 'loading_date_time',
              'unloading_date_time', 'due_amount', 'trip_profit',
              'ph_number', 'cargo_weight', 'vehicle_type', 'loading_address',
              'trip_distance', 'unloading_address',
              ]
```

hear I  cus_name as user name which is the user customer can login

**View**

```
class TestAPIBookingOnly(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [UserRenderers]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def post(self, request, format=False):

        serial = TestBookingSerializer(data=request.data, partial=True)

        if serial.is_valid():
            token = get_tokens_for_user(serial)
            serial.save()
            return Response({'token': token, 'msg': 'Data Entry Successful',
                     }, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serial.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: 1. `get_tokens_for_user(serial)` must be `get_tokens_for_user(request.user)`, 2. If I can understand this part of code correctly `get_tokens_for_user` returning user's session token. I don't understand relationship of user login session and booking id. Looks like this code doesn't doing what was planned to do.

Comment: dear this booking_id is nothing . i'ts generate only random number after creating new row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my thinking, you should first get the id of the user by this code and put this user_id in the get_token_for_user() method:

```
def post(self, request, format=False):
    user_id = self.request.user.id
    serial = TestBookingSerializer(data=request.data, partial=True)

    if serial.is_valid():
        token = get_tokens_for_user(user_id)
        serial.save()
        return Response({'token': token, 'msg': 'Data Entry Successful',
                 }, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    return Response(serial.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: According error message `serial` in `get_tokens_for_user(serial)` should be a valid instance of `user` Model. But not integer value of `id`. In other words `get_tokens_for_user(request.user)`

Comment: thank you dear. the problem has been solved.